# Find the slope using variables from another file in Java

Tags: java, class

I'm doing this project where I need to have this specific class structure and find the slope. I need to somehow find the slope using points 1  and 2 (p1, p2).

```
//file MyPoint

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MyPoint {

    private double x;
    private double y;

    public MyPoint() {
        double xP = x;
        double yP = y;
    }

    public double getX(double x) {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY(double y) {
        return y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        DecimalFormat df_obj = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        return "(" + df_obj.format(getX(x)) + "," + df_obj.format(getY(y)) + ")";
    }

}



//file MyLine

public class MyLine {

    private MyPoint p1;
    private MyPoint p2;
    private double slope;
    private double xint;
    private double yint;

    public MyLine(MyPoint p1, MyPoint p2) {
        p1 = new MyPoint();
        p2 = new MyPoint();
    }

    public static MyPoint getPointOne(MyPoint p1) {
        return p1;
    }

    public static MyPoint getPointTwo(MyPoint p2) {
        return p2;
    }

    public static double getSlope() {
        double slope = //don't know what to put here in order to get the slope from p1 and p2;
        return slope;
    }

}
```

Comment: What *do* you know about calculating the slope of a line?

Comment: Why is "getScope" declared as static? If it is non-static you can write a formula using p1 and p2 to get the slope. Same with your other static "getPointOne" make it non-static and return p1.

Comment: Why are you calling a double field `xint` or `yint`?  How about just `x and y`?  And as @matt said, make you getters instance methods (i.e. non-static).

Comment: @WJS sorry I’m brand new to Java and I don’t know much about programming. This is a lab for a CS class, and my other programming comes from Python (which I never got into classes with). This is new to me

Comment: @ScottHunter I do know about slope, just I’m not very knowledgeable on Java in the slightest. I just started learning

Comment: @EvanMiller Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour] to see what this site is about.  And also read [ask].  Regarding `xint` and `yint` what I meant was they aren't `ints` but `doubles`.  Usually one names variables something meaningful.  Since `x` and `y` are meaningful in an algebraic context, they could be used without including the type as part of the name.  But that is your decision.

Comment: @WJS ohh those are going to reference the x intercept and y intercept. Would it be better practice to change the name?

Comment: Well chosen names contribute to code documentation.   So one might find `double xInt` confusing or misleading further in the code.   Check out the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The slope is calculated as `rise/run` which means `delta Y` divided by `delta X`.

```
double slope = (p1.getY() - p2.getY())/(p1.getX() - p2.getX());
```

and the equation of the line is `y = slope*x + b` where `b` is the `y-intercept` (where the line crosses the `y-axis` if extended that far).

```
double b = y - slope*x;  // use either point for x,y
```

Answer (score -1):

A common slope calculation between 2 points would be:

```
    slope = DeltaY / DeltaX = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
```

So in your getSlope() method you'd use:

```
    double slope = (p2.getY() - p1.getY()) / (p2.getX() - p1.getX());
```

By the way I think there are a couple of mistakes in your code:

1. your getX() and getY() don't need to have 'x' and 'y' respectively as parameters. The x and y values are inside the MyPoint class' p1 and p2 instances.
2. On the other hand, the MyPoint constructor needs to receive the 'x' and 'y' parameters, in order to assign them to the inner xP and yP variables respectively.